# Is there a way to have a dynamic query or execute multiple queries with an apache beam pipeline?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using apache beam & google cloud dataflow to insert information into a cloud SQL database. So far this has been working great writing to one table. The information that is being sent is being broadened, including information destined to another table in the database.

I was curious if there was a way to dynamically use an SQL query based on the information I am receiving or am I able to somehow create the pipeline to execute multiple queries? Either would work...

Or, am I stuck with having to create a separate pipeline?

Cheers,

EDIT: Adding my current pipeline config

```
MainPipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    MainPipeline.apply(PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription(MAIN_SUBSCRIPTION))
    .apply(JdbcIO.<String> write()
        .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver", JDBC_URL)
            .withUsername(JDBC_USER).withPassword(JDBC_PASS))
        .withStatement(QUERY_SQL).withPreparedStatementSetter(new NewPreparedStatementSetter() {
        }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can have dynamic queries on `JdbcIO` based on the input elements, it's configured once at construction time as far as I can see.

However, I can think of couple of potential workarounds if they suit your use case.

One is to just to write your own `ParDo` in which you would call the JDBC driver manually. This will be basically re-implementing some part of the `JdbcIO` with new features added. Such `ParDo` can be as flexible as you like.

Another is to split the input `PColleciton` into [multiple outputs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/design-your-pipeline/#a-single-transform-that-produces-multiple-outputs). That will work if your use case is limited to some predefined set of queries that you can choose from based on the input. This way you split the input into multiple `PCollections` and then attach differently configured IOs to each.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I am actually working on splitting the input collection as you responded. I had though about calling the JDBC drivers manuals, but I wanted to save that for the last case scenario. Cheers.